# my dropdown menu is not working in navigation-bar

Tags: html, css

My dropdown should appear vertically after hovering on the partners , services and about button.But the dropdown is not appearing.

The dropdown should fall upon my slide show ,but it is not working.

MAIN ISSUE: DROPDOWN in NAV BAR not working

```
        <body>

        <div class="navbar" id="myTopnav">
          <a href="#home">Home</a>



          <div class="subnav">
            <button class="subnavbtn">About <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div class="subnav-content">
              <a href="#company">Company</a>
              <a href="#team">Team</a>
              <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="subnav">
            <button class="subnavbtn">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div class="subnav-content">
              <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
              <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
              <a href="#package">Package</a>
              <a href="#express">Express</a>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="subnav">
            <button class="subnavbtn">Partners <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
            <div class="subnav-content">
              <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
              <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#contact">Contact</a>


          <div class="topnav-right">
          <div class="wrap">
             <div class="search">
                <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search?">
                <button type
                ="submit" class="searchButton">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
               </button>
             </div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>

          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="assets\images\index\slider1.jpg"  alt="Chania" class="center" width="500" height="345" >
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>h3</h3>
                <p>Text for slide3</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="assets\images\index\slider2.jpg" alt="Chania" class="center" width="500" height="345">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>h3</h3>
                <p>Text for slide2</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="assets\images\index\slider3.jpg" alt="Flower" class="center" width="500" height="345">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h3>h3</h3>
                <p>Text for slide1</p>
              </div>
            </div>


          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>





        nav {
          margin: 0 auto;
          padding: 0;
          width: 78%;
          background-color: #757575;
        }

        .navbar navbar-default {
          background-color: #757575;
        }

        a {
          float: left;
          display: block;
          color: #f2f2f2;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 17px;
        }


        .footer {
          position: fixed;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
          width: 100%;
          background-color: #757575;
          color: white;
          text-align: left;
        }


        /* The navigation menu */

        .navbar {
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;

        }


        /* Navigation links */

        .navbar a {
          float: left;
          font-size: 16px;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }


        /* The subnavigation menu */

        .subnav {
          float: left;
          overflow: hidden;
        }


        /* Subnav button */

        .subnav .subnavbtn {
          font-size: 16px;
          border: none;
          outline: none;
          color: white;
          padding: 14px 16px;
          background-color: inherit;
          font-family: inherit;
          margin: 0;
        }


        /* Add a red background color to navigation links on hover */

        .navbar a:hover,
        .subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
          background-color: red;
        }


        /* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */

        .subnav-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          background-color: red;
          width: 100%;
          z-index: 1;
        }


        /* Style the subnav links */

        .subnav-content a {
          float: left;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
        }


        /* Add a grey background color on hover */

        .subnav-content a:hover {
          background-color: #eee;
          color: black;
        }


        /* When you move the mouse over the subnav container, open the subnav content */

        .subnav:hover .subnav-content {
          display: block;
        }

        input[type=text] {
          width: 130px;
          -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
          transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
        }


        /* When the input field gets focus, change its width to 100% */

        input[type=text]:focus {
          width: 100%;
        }

        * {
          font-family: arial;
        }
```

Comment: please provide HTML code in one block, not in parts. Also, provide your CSS

Comment: please modify 

```
        .subnav:hover .subnav-content {
            display: block;
        }
``` 
to 

```
        .subnavbtn:hover + .subnav-content {
            display: block;
        }
```

Comment: its not working sir, pls someone help me with this

Comment: please check the code in my answer

Answer (score 0):

please check the working code below. You had the main `navbar` set to overflow hidden, that is why the content (dropdown) was not showing. I have fixed that. Hope it works for you!

```css
nav {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 78%;
  background-color: #757575;
}

.navbar navbar-default {
  background-color: #757575;
}

a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #757575;
  color: white;
  text-align: left;
}

/* The navigation menu */

.navbar {
/*   overflow: hidden; */
  background-color: #333;
}

/* Navigation links */

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* The subnavigation menu */

.subnav {
  float: left;
/*   overflow: hidden; */
}

/* Subnav button */

.subnav .subnavbtn {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Add a red background color to navigation links on hover */

.navbar a:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

/* Style the subnav content - positioned absolute */

.subnav-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the subnav links */

.subnav-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Add a grey background color on hover */

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}

/* When you move the mouse over the subnav container, open the subnav content */

.subnav:hover .subnav-content {
  display: block;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 130px;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

/* When the input field gets focus, change its width to 100% */

input[type="text"]:focus {
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">About <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#company">Company</a>
      <a href="#team">Team</a>
      <a href="#careers">Careers</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Services <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#bring">Bring</a>
      <a href="#deliver">Deliver</a>
      <a href="#package">Package</a>
      <a href="#express">Express</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="subnav">
    <button class="subnavbtn">Partners <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>
    <div class="subnav-content">
      <a href="#link1">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#link2">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#link3">Link 3</a>
      <a href="#link4">Link 4</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

  <div class="topnav-right">
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="search">
        <input type="text" class="searchTerm" placeholder="Search?">
        <button type="submit" class="searchButton">
                  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
               </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```